# How to use xmltodict.parse with non-printable data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, xmltodict

I tried to convert xml to dict with Python

```
import xmltodict
xmltodict.parse('<a>as\x08</a>')
```

But I got an exception

```
ExpatError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-XXXXXX> in <module>
----> 1 xmltodict.parse('<a>as\x08</a>')

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xmltodict.py in parse(xml_input, encoding, expat, process_namespaces, namespace_separator, disable_entities, process_comments, **kwargs)
    376         parser.Parse(b'',True)
    377     else:
--> 378         parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
    379     return handler.item
    380

ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5
```

How can I use xmltodict library with non-printable char

Comment: As the error message is telling you, the input is not valid XML.  Nothing to do with xmltodict.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That valid XML , but with binary data....

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets <- nulls are not in the range of permitted characters.